# Trying to find a book about a forest that absorbs people

Tags: story-identification, books

Help everyone.
I'm trying to find a book I read in the early 90's at school. It wasn't a class study, just a book I stumbled upon in the library.
The only issue is I recall very little about it.

I think it was set in modern times eg; 70s through to the 90s but uncertain. I remember that a forest existed and some of the trees absorbed people into their trunks.

I also recall that their was a man that was actually a tree but he could take on the form of a human, he would kidnap people and take them to the trees in the forest.

I believe there was a teenage boy or young man that was trying to figure out what was going on and also attempting to stop the "tree man".

That's really all I can remember and I'm not sure how accurate that even was. The cover I think was art work of a forest on the front and the spine and back were plain black.

I have read the plot of *The Soldier's Son* and that doesn't really sound like what I remember however the part where the sick or dying were given to the trees kind of sounded familiar but the rest of the plot is extremely unfamiliar especially the giant tree and it being on another planet.

I know it's a long shot but any theories will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at "[Balanced Ecology](http://www.webscription.net/10.1125/Baen/0671319841/0671319841___3.htm)", by James H Schmitz?  I'm not sure this is the story you're looking for, but it has enough similarities it might be worth checking out.  I read it in the collection *[The Hub: Dangerous territory](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/128887.The_Hub)*.

Matches include a forest that eats several people, a person (called "Sam") who grabs at least one person and maybe decides others should be grabbed and vanished, and a boy who is trying to figure out what's happening and stop the bad guys.  The time frame is off, being both future and another world, but the legal and social terms are similar enough to modern times that it might overshadow the setting a bit in memory.

Misses are that it isn't a book, but a short story, that the antagonists are the people who get eaten (the forest claims self defense), Sam is a mobile part of the forest that is personified, but doesn't actually turn human, and sick or dying are not given to the trees in the story.

I hope this helps.